# Implement animated background in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am learning Cocos2d-x and I wish to create a animated background in a game "Duet" in iOS.

**This is video of Duet:**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Tq4t0gx49g

Is is possible with Cocos2d-x? And if yes, then how can I optimize it ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Why would you want to optimize it if you don't even know if (and presumably how) it's possible to accomplish it with cocos2d? That 2nd question including how to do it is too broad. You could start by putting sprites in the background and animate them with scale and move actions.

Comment: I just want to know if I can create an animated background like the game "Duet" because I see it is beautiful. I have searched over Google but I can't find a tutorial about how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Okay but simple Yes/No questions are not suitable for SO. There's unlikely a tutorial for that because that can be done quite simply (sprite anims using actions), or quite complex (OpenGL rendering, perhaps with shaders).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will be more careful in my next question. I'm trying to make that background in simple way now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out ParallaxNode: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/d0/dd1/classcocos2d_1_1_parallax_node.html